# IOS not saving cookie from express cookie-session

Tags: ios, express, https, passport.js, session-cookies

This problem has been driving me mad. I am using React with Apollo (GraphQL) on the frontend and authenticating using passport.js and express `cookie-session` on the backend. Everything works perfectly from any browser (haven't tested safari) on a desktop, however the cookie does not save on IOS and the user cannot login. This problem only happens using `passport-local` and if the browser does not already have a cookie. If I login using `passport-google` or `passport-facebook` it works, then if I logout and use `passport-local` again, it works, even if it's a different user. Also, it works the first time around if I go to my settings and turn off "Prevent Cross-Site Tracking" for IOS Safari, however I can't turn that off if I want to use this as a PWA.

My express setup looks like this (leaving out all the imports):

```
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30,
    keys: [process.env.COOKIE_KEY],
    overwrite: true
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());

const whitelist = [
  "https://toomanylists.com",
  "https://www.toomanylists.com"
];

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      console.log(origin);
      if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error("blocked by CORS"));
      }
    },
    credentials: true
  })
);

app.options("*", cors());

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to Database");
});

const authCheck = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect("https://toomanylists.com");
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  authCheck,
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
```

My login route:

```
router.post("/login", jsonParser, (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("user-login", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify(info));
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(info));
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

In React I am sending the request using fetch API:

```
fetch(<my_server_url/login>, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
      }).then(response => {
        //if fails alerts with custom message
        if (response.status === 401) {
          response.json().then(json => {
            alert(json.message);
          });
        } //if successful refresh with cookies
        if (response.status === 200) {
          window.location.reload(false);
        }
      });
```

Another, maybe related, issue is that if I add `{secure: true}` option to `cookie-session` it doesn't work at all, even though I am using a valid SSL cert through AWS where the frontend is hosted in an S3 bucket. The backend is on heroku and also is https. The site is live if it helps for anyone to check it out and try using it and inspecting the dev tools. I haven't tested it on android or ipad yet. https://toomanylists.com

Anyway, I suppose this is a long shot but I am hoping maybe there is something easy I am missing and it is not an unsolvable IOS issue with my setup and them preventing cookies (is this new in IOS 12?). Also, does anyone know if this would also be an issue using JWT's and if that is a secure way to authenticate users?

Comment: Just stumbled upon a similar issue. iOS 12.1 and `express-session` do not work together properly. Session is being initialized however additional values are not being stored.

Comment: I am having an issue with this too. On PC and android, everything thing works perfect.... on IOS(IPAD) the sessions get created for every request made instead of using existing session. Also properties stored on session dont apear in the store. Did you guys figure this out?

Comment: any solutions yet? Works on Safari on the PC, but not on the Iphone's safari......

Comment: Not sure if there is a solution yet, I haven't been working in Node in over a year now

Comment: Pls how did you solve this issue? Any solution yet?

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: I am still unable to solve this issue. I have no idea why this is happening. Do you find any solution yet? @AndrewLeonardi

Comment: @Paulliano Yes for sure. Check this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384430/cookies-only-set-in-chrome-not-set-in-safari-mobile-chrome-or-mobile-safari

Comment: Thank you so much, I would try it out. @AndrewLeonardi

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a thousand solutions to this but here was mine.

I need to use CORS in dev, but not in production. Both sets of code below are needed for CORS (I think) but I'd only had the first one checking to see if my environment variable `use_cors` was true. Once I removed the CORS-related headers in production (the variable is set to false in prod) by putting the if statement around them, the issue was resolved.

Long-story short: Whether you're using CORS or not, make sure your headers are correct.

```
//Set up CORS in development, but not in production
if (process.env.USE_CORS === 'true') {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: process.env.CLIENT,
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'],
      credentials: true
    })
  )
}

//Set CORS Headers in development, but not in production
if (process.env.SET_CORS_HEADERS === 'true') {
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept')
    next()
  })
}
```