# Cookies Only set in Chrome - not set in Safari, Mobile Chrome, or Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, cross-domain, csrf

I have a working sign up and sign in end point when using desktop browsers (only Chrome), but when trying to sign up or sign in using a mobile browser, the server times out. I suspect this is because my session cookies and csurf cookies are not being sent over with my fetch request.

I have opened Safari development on my mobile browser, and it does not show any cookies. I suspect now that this is because of MaxAge --

Note that my api and client are on separate domains, Heroku and Netlify. See the code below:

CORS Options

```
const options = {

  origin: "clientUrl",
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "Authorization",
    "csrf-token"
  ],
  exposedHeaders: [
    "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "Authorization",
    "csrf-token"
  ],

  maxAge: 3600,
  preflightContinue: true,
  credentials: true
};
```

CSURF Config

```
app.use(
  csurf({
    cookie: true,
    domain: "clientUrl",
    sameSite: "none"
  })
);
```

Express Session Config

```
app.use(
  session({
    //This is our Encryption Key
    secret: process.env.sessionCode,
    //We set resave to false because our mongo store implements the "touch" function
    resave: false,
    //We Set saveUninitialized to false because we don't want to save unmodified
    //sessions to our mongo store
    secure: true,
    domain: "clientUrl",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    unset: "destroy",
    sameSite: "none",
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      //We encrypt out store code
      code: process.env.storeCode
    })
  })
);
```

Comment: Have you checked the cookie Preferences of the mobile browser ? If it was disabled somehow then you code might be failed.

Comment: Yeah - it allows them. :(

Comment: Can you confirm that the save fetch request on the same page does carrier any cookie and send to service successfully?

Comment: On desktop it has to, or else the sign in auth wouldn’t work.

Comment: I thought maybe this was an issue with third party cookies not being allowed in mobile.

Comment: Hopefully,  https://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains/ would help.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - do you have any insight into this? It's working fine in Chrome and Firefox. Just not Safari.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don’t have any insight beyond just the fact it’s not related to CORS (which is why I removed the [cors] tag). If there were any CORS problem, the browser would be logging a specific CORS error in the devtools console. So I think you can at least rule out there being any problems in your CORS config.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree - it works on localhost. Something in safari is not allowing CORs

Comment: What's your chrome version?

Comment: Safari does not allow cross-domain cookies. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari

Comment: There appears to be no way around the issue, Safari needs the setting to be changed manually. Having a cross domain api is an awful idea for session management.

Comment: I just launched my web app and ran into the same problem. Chrome on iOS seems to have jumped on the same bandwagon. No cross domain cookies, meaning iphones cant log in to my site :/. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Chano I never found a solution. I wound up simply hosting the front end on the same domain as the backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a battle I've figured this out with the help of this post [Setting a domain with Express sessions stops cookie from being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569718/setting-a-domain-with-express-sessions-stops-cookie-from-being-saved).

The issue comes down to third party cookies.

If you're sending data from *server.herokuapp.com* to *site.herokuapp.com* you're going to have this issue. **The solution is to use the same  custom  domain for both your frontend and backend Heroku applications.**

You should add a custom domain to your frontend and a subdomain to your backend Heroku application. Frontend should look like mywebsite.com and backend should look like server.mywebsite.com.

Within your DNS the subdomain should be *server* in this example and point to the Heroku DNS target for the backend. The frontend subdomain should be @ or www and point to the Heroku DNS target for the frontend.

Once your applications are being served from the same URL and you have cors set up you will no longer have any third party cookie issues.

You can read more about this [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com)

Comment: I've tried everything I can, nothing seems to work for me. Pls is there any other solution you think might solve this? I have applied this answer but it didnot solve my problem

Comment: Are you using Heroku for both your frontend and backend?