# req.user is undefined - Passport JS with node and React in web host (works on local host)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, passport.js

in local host ive started the server in port 4000 and the client in 3000.I've tried several stack overfow posts (problem with cors, session config) but nothing improved my results. The following code worked as expeced and fetched the user for my function **logInUser()**.

this is how i click the G button from Front end

```
const loginFn = () => {window.open(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/auth/google`, "_self")}
```

this is my app.js (server)

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
  saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
  cookie: { httpOnly: false, maxAge: (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000) },
}));

app.use(cors({
  origin: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`,
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.authenticate('session'));

app.use("/auth", authrouter);
app.use("/item", itemrouter);
app.use("/cart", cartrouter);
app.use("/pay", payrouter);
app.use("/purchasehistory", purchasehistoryrouter);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ "status": "server active" })
})
```

Google Strategy

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: `${process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}`,
    clientSecret: `${process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
    callbackURL: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/auth/google/callback`,
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
}, async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) { .... }
```

serialise and deserialiser

```
passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    // console.log(user);
    process.nextTick(() => {
        cb(null, user._id);
    });
    console.log("---------------------serialised")
});

passport.deserializeUser((_id, cb) => {
    // console.log(_id);
    process.nextTick(() => {
        userDetails.findById(_id, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("user not foud for deserialisation")
                throw err;
            }
            else {
                console.log("---------------------deserialised")
                return cb(null, user);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**from here im forwarding my user to the client side**

```
const authorize = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (req.user) {
            res.status(200).json(req.user)
        }
        else {
            console.log("req.user not found")
            res.status(403).json({
                status: false,
                message: "req.user not found"
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("unautherised")
        res.status(401).json({ status: false, message: "unautherised" })
    }
}
```

the below code fetches the user for me at the client side

```
 axios({
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/auth/authorize`,
      method: 'get',
      withCredentials: true
    })
      .then((resp) => {
        if (resp.status === 200) {
          console.log("success")
          logInUser(true, resp.data);
          console.log(resp.data)
          toast.success(`${resp.data.fName} logged-in`);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error api fetch: ")
        console.log(err)
        logOutUser();
      })
```

*Ive made the following change on the session config while deploying.*

```
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
  saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
  cookie: { httpOnly: false, secure: true, sameSite: "none", maxAge: (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000) },
}));
```

what i've tried

- different config for session
- cookie session instead of express session
- different config for cors
- added *passport.authorize()* middileware on the route to be protected
- hosting both server and client on Heroku (when i fed-up)

what i didn't tried

- using proxy server

*i'm missing something that i didn't know. I know there are lots of post related to this issue. but i couldn't make anything useful for me. Please share your advice for this issue. Thanks in advance*

[I'm attaching the logs collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CYwO.jpg)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I am also having this problem, pls how did you solve this? @AndrewLeonardi

Comment: @Paulliano I posted the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384430/cookies-only-set-in-chrome-not-set-in-safari-mobile-chrome-or-mobile-safari/73587844#73587844

Comment: I've already done this. Pls is there anything you think might be causing this?

Comment: @Paulliano Be sure to read this post and make sure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569718/setting-a-domain-with-express-sessions-stops-cookie-from-being-saved

Comment: I've already done that