# Safari not allowing third party cookies due to cross site tracking enabled

Tags: safari, express-session

So I built an app that uses passport and express session for its authentication. When I deployed, I discovered that safari was not letting express session work until I switched off 'cross site tracking' in its settings. How do I make this work?

Based on this article https://sarav.co/session-persisting-issue-safari I need to manually switch it off, but I honestly cannot expect my users to be manually doing that.

Below is how I've set up my express session:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
    },
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: process.env.DB_URL,
        ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        autoRemove: 'native',
    })
}));
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Basically it’s to create a sub-domain, which involves money that I don’t have

Comment: Thanks! I came to the same conclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384430/cookies-only-set-in-chrome-not-set-in-safari-mobile-chrome-or-mobile-safari

Comment: Do you plan on creating one?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked flawlessly

Comment: That's really nice. How much did it cost you if you don't mind?

Comment: Cheap! I'd say you can find a domain on GoDaddy for under $10

Comment: Does the domain come with a sub-domain? Or do I have to pay for that also? Sorry for the plenty questions

Comment: No worries at all. You only need one domain. Within the DNS settings you can set up a (free) subdomain. So it would be website.com and server.website.com for your backend. Check out the link a few comments above where I go into more detail