# Axios request blocked regardless of CORS settings - 503 error

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, use-effect, http-status-code-503

I've tried just about every suggestion out there to solve a CORS issue (47 different ways to be exact). I'm beginning to think the issue is not on CORS side but in how my axios request is set up. **My question is simple: Is it possible my issue is with my axios setup and not with my server side CORS set up?**

*Error: Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Frontend React

```
  useEffect(async () => {
      const result = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        withCredentials: true,
        url: "site-backend.herokuapp.com",
      }).then((res) => {
        setMasterUserAccount(res.data.username);
      });
    }, []);
```

Backend Express/Node: CORS

```
    const cors = require("cors");
    
    var corsOptions = {
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
      origin: "https://site.herokuapp.com",
      optionSuccessStatus: 200,
      credentials: true,
    };
    
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Here's the response from the network tab:

```
Request URL: https://site-backend.herokuapp.com/userData
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 503 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 506
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2022 16:54:44 GMT
Server: Cowboy
Accept: application/json, text/plain, 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: site-backend.herokuapp.com
Origin: https://site.herokuapp.com
Referer: https://site.herokuapp.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

Comment: It'd be handy to include the exact request that's failing, e.g., is it an `OPTIONS` request?

Comment: The GET request in the useEffect is what is failing

Comment: In your CORS config, is `origin` a valid [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin)? Did you (you shouldn't) include any path in it?

Comment: @jub0bs Thanks for the suggestion. Yep it's a valid web origin without any path or trailing /

Comment: It'd be handy to include the exact request that's failing, e.g., the *actual request* as shown in the network tab (as curl or even an image).

Comment: @DaveNewton I added the network tab response. Let me know if that is what you're looking for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The response details show that the response is a 503 error. Server systems don’t add application-set errors to 5xx responses. So the root problem is whatever’s causing that 503 error on the server side. Any CORS messages on the client side are just a side effect of that.

Comment: Not sure what is dummy value here and what is the actual value. Does `origin` from the request match `origin` from `corsOptions`?

Comment: @mbojko Thanks for the suggestion. It does. I've updated the code to match above.

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi As sideshow said the 503 may indicate it's actually *not* a CORS issue, rather a server issue. Are you able to make any *other* requests to the server, via the app/curl/Postman/etc?

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly enough my POST routes work fine and return 200. Somethings happening with this GET route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get to the bottom of this. In the GET function above what I was doing was setting a username state. This was failing because even though the user had been authenticated (via passport.js) the req.user was failing, thus causing a 503 and showing the confusing error: "*Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*"

Thanks for the comments above from Dave & Sideshow explaining that 503 may indicate it's actually not a CORS issue, rather a server issue. I was convinced it was failing to connect to the database/server at all but this was not the case.

My recommendation if facing this issue is to check the **route** you're hitting and try to determine what could cause it to fail thus throwing a 503.

**UPDATE**: This ended up being do to a larger underlining issue with third party cookies and Heroku. See the solution here: [Cookies Only set in Chrome - not set in Safari, Mobile Chrome, or Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384430/cookies-only-set-in-chrome-not-set-in-safari-mobile-chrome-or-mobile-safari/73587844#73587844)